# Android Image does not change when retrieve that from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, bitmap, android-sqlite

Another problem I have with retrieve image (Blob) when retrieve an image will be show and if I change image from record of database to another one of image, previous image will be cash does n't change to a new image..!
Datbase table:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(" +
                    "Sid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                    "firstName TEXT, " +
                    "lastName TEXT, " +
                    "photo  BLOB, " +
                    "book TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
   }
```

Manually inserted some data

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("firstName", "Roza");
    values.put("lastName", "Jack");
            // profile picture of sudent
    values.put("photo", convertimg(R.drawable.sudent_1));
    values.put("book", "Andriod programming");
    db.insert("student", "book", values);
```

convert method image to BLOB

```
public static byte[] convertimg(int drawimg)
{
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myresurse, drawimg);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , bos);
            byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

    return bitmapdata;

}
```

and retrieve image and set to imageview.

```
db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("select firstname || '  ' || lastname as fullname,book,photo from student where Sid=1" , null);

    cur.moveToNext();


              ImageView imgprofile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.studentphoto);

              byte[] mybyte=cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex("photo"));


      ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(mybyte);

      Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream); 

      imgprofile.setImageBitmap(theImage);

              imgprofile.invalidate();
```

my big problem is here if I want to change previous image

```
values.put("photo", convertimg(R.drawable.sudent_1));
```

to an image like this second image does not show instead first image

```
values.put("photo", convertimg(R.drawable.sudent_2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `imgprofile.invalidate();` after setting `imgprofile.setImageBitmap(theImage);`. This will basically redraw the ImageView.

Comment: thank you but until I have the problem, I used imgprofile.invalidate();

Comment: I didn't get what you said ? Have you already used invalidate() method ?

Comment: you meaning about my question or what ?

Comment: have you used invalidate() method in your code ? I can't see.

Comment: Yes I used it ` imgprofile.setImageBitmap(theImage);
      
      imgprofile.invalidate();`

Comment: Ok. See in your code it's not there. That's why I asked you whether you have used invalidate() or not ?

Comment: after you answered me then I was added it into my code from my Eclipse project but have the same problem the image dos not changed :) thank you very much.